# Primefaces datatable right click

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am fixing a PrimeFaces panel with a file downloader where you select a file from a list and download it.

Right now first you have to select the file with a left click and then right click and select "download file".

Most people however are used to right click on a file and select "download it".

As you can see from the code below when you select a file the actionlistener actionListener="#{downloadsController.selectFile}" is called which correctly sets the file name to be downloaded and then the right click calls actionListener="#{downloadsController.downloadFile}".

How can I make selectFile be called when right click is called? or let right click access the 
file.name ?

```
<p:panel id="propPanel">
    <h:form>
        <p:contextMenu for="fileExplorer">
            <p:menuitem value="Download" actionListener="#{downloadsController.downloadFile}" 
                icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" ajax="false" >
                <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadsController.fileToDownload}" />
            </p:menuitem>
        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:scrollPanel style="height:300px">  
            <p:dataTable id="fileExplorer" var="file" value="#{downloadsController.files}" 
                emptyMessage="This folder is empty"
                 rowKey="#{file.name}" selectionMode="single" >
                <p:column style="width:308px" sortBy="#{file.name}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Name
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:commandLink style=" text-decoration: none;" 
                        actionListener="#{downloadsController.selectFile}" update=":treePanel">
                        <f:param name="fileName" value="#{file.name}"/>
                        <p:spacer width="5" height="10" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{file.name}" escape="false"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:55px" sortBy="#{file.size}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Size
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{file.size}" escape="false">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:scrollPanel> 
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Primefaces 4 you could simply use row selection as demonstrated [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableContextMenu.jsf).

```
<p:contextMenu for="cars">  
...
</p:contextMenu>  
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" rowKey="#{car.model}"  
                 selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single">
...
</p:dataTable>
```